# flutter downloader and path provider

Tags: flutter, path

I'm new to flutter and i have been trying a lot , I have managed to make flutter downloader and the path provider work on android but it won't work on IOS saying that this is a android only operation , what's wrong ? here is the code :

```
secondaryActions: <Widget>[
        IconSlideAction(
          caption: 'Download',
          color: Colors.green,
          icon: Icons.arrow_circle_down,
          onTap: () async {
            final status = await Permission.storage.request();
            if (status.isGranted) {
              final externalDir = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
              final id = await FlutterDownloader.enqueue(
                  url: f.url,
                  savedDir: externalDir.path,
                  showNotification: true,
                  openFileFromNotification: true);
            } else {
              toast('Permission Denied');
            }
          },
```

Comment: Could you show the packages you import and also the definitions of any user defined functions used here

Comment: there is no functions , i have used the slider , flutter downloader and path provider packages